# iOS WKWebView not showing javascript alert() dialog

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

I am having some trouble getting a WKWebView in iOS 8 to display an alert dialog that is called from Javascript. After creating a standard WKWebView and loading an HTML file, I have a button on the page that creates a simple alert with some text. This works in UIWebView and in Google Chrome/Safari, but does not appear to be working in WKWebView. Any help is appreciated.

My setup is as follows:

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
config.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
config.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false;
_wkViewWeb = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:_viewWeb.frame config];
_wkViewWeb.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
NSString *fullURL = @"file://.../TestSlide.html";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10];

[_wkViewWeb loadRequest:request];
```

The html has the following function:

```
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
function alertTest() {
    alert("Testing Alerts");
}
</SCRIPT>
```

And a button:

```
<b>Test Alerts: <input type="button" value="Alert Popup" onclick="alertTest()"><br></b> <br>
```

This setup works in UIWebView and in regular browsers, but does not work in WKWebView. Am I missing something in the configuration? Should I be using one of the WK delegates to control the alert/confirm dialog behavior? Thank you.

Comment: can u try hosting the html file and try "http://" instead of "file://", it may be because of this bug in wkwebview: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5839348817723392

Comment: The html files are stored locally so they can be accessed offline. The file loads without an issue, its only the alert dialog that does not display when the button is tapped.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

To solve this you need a WKUIDelegate for your web view. It is the duty of the delegate to decide if an alert should be displayed, and in what way. You need to implement this for alert, confirm and text input (prompt).

Here is sample code without any validation of the page url or security features:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:message
                                                                             message:nil
                                                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                        style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                          completionHandler();
                                                      }]];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

More in the [Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKUIDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WKUIDelegate/webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:completionHandler:)

Comment: If you still don't get this delegate function called, remember to try the other two: `runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage` and `runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt`. The event depends on the type of the alert.

Comment: There is a great boilerplate for the implementation of all 3 delegate methods here: https://gist.github.com/davbeck/8613f2e74e8fc335c14d

Comment: This not work for wkwebview's  evaluateJavaScript(), refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/43600624/6521116

Answer (score 61):

**Swift 3** with all 3 optional functions implemented:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
             completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler()
    }))

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
             completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler(true)
    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler(false)
    }))

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String, defaultText: String?, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
             completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: prompt, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.text = defaultText
    }

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        if let text = alertController.textFields?.first?.text {
            completionHandler(text)
        } else {
            completionHandler(defaultText)
        }
    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler(nil)
    }))

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: where this code should be inserted? I insert this directly in the `class ViewController` - it compiles, but my JS isnt able to trigger `prompt()`

Comment: @godblessstrawberry  It should be inserted in your WKView's uiDelegate (WKUIDelegate), typically a view controller that implements that protocol.

Comment: @Crashalot: Just change (preferredStyle: .alert) and it will work like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Also, you need to add this inside your viewController : `webView.uiDelegate = self;`

Comment: For the preferredStyle, use UIAlertController.Style.alert instead of .actionSheet.

Answer (score 21):

Just to expand a bit, `WKWebView` requires you to show alerts, prompts, and confirms yourself. Do this by becoming a `WKUIDelegate`:

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
@interface MyController : UIViewController<WKUIDelegate>
```

Then assign the delegate:

```
web.UIDelegate = self;
```

Then you need to actually implement alert, prompt, and confirm. I create [WKWebViewPanelManager.h/m](https://gist.github.com/bendytree/5d87a1df51ea38d595c3) as an easy implementation, so here's what I do:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
    [WKWebViewPanelManager presentAlertOnController:self.view.window.rootViewController title:@"Alert" message:message handler:completionHandler];
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL result))completionHandler {
    [WKWebViewPanelManager presentConfirmOnController:self.view.window.rootViewController title:@"Confirm" message:message handler:completionHandler];
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt:(NSString *)prompt defaultText:(nullable NSString *)defaultText initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame completionHandler:(void (^)(NSString * __nullable result))completionHandler {
    [WKWebViewPanelManager presentPromptOnController:self.view.window.rootViewController title:@"Prompt" message:prompt defaultText:defaultText handler:completionHandler];
}
```

Of course, it's up to you to filter out bad alert/confirm/prompt requests.

Answer (score 16):

And here's that in [swift](/questions/tagged/swift):

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String,
             initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: message,
                                            message: nil,
                                            preferredStyle: .alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel) {
        _ in completionHandler()}
    )

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

1. Implement the protocol to your WKWebview container controller. **WKUIDelegate**
2. Add preference to **WKWebview** to enable javascript in **viewDidLoad()** as.

   ```
   // enable JS
   webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
   ```
3. Register **WKWebview** UI Delegate in **viewDidLoad()** as

   ```
   self.webView.uiDelegate = self
   ```
4. Implement the below delegate in your class.

   ```
   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: 
   String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> 
   Void) {
   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: message,message: nil,preferredStyle: 
   .alert)

   alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel) {_ in 
   completionHandler()})

   self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

Comment: The method signature has changed : func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) ...

Answer (score 6):

Here is the code in **Swift 4.2**

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String,
             initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: message, message: nil,
                                            preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert);

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel) {
        _ in completionHandler()}
    );

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {});
}
```

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'UIAlertController'. Using XCode 10.2 and Swift 5

Answer (score 0):

1. The viewController

```
ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate
```

2. Enable JavaScript

```
webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
```

3. In the ViewDidLoad() Function add the below items

```
   webView.uiDelegate = self
   webView.navigationDelegate = self
   view.addSubview(webView)
```

4. Add the delegate as follows

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String,
                 initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
                 completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let title = NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "OK Button")
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: title, style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        alert.addAction(ok)
        present(alert, animated: true)
        completionHandler()
    }
```