# WKWebView - Javascript Confirm and Alert not working

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I am using WKWebView to open up example.com, and on there I have a test link which is supposed to open up a JS alert, but I can't get it to display on the device, it only works if I view the site from browser.

I am using WKUIDelegate, and added this piece of code to the ViewController.swift file:

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: (() -> Void)) {

    NSLog("Hello")
}
```

I don't see anything in the XCode console when I click the link that spawns the JS alert.

What am I missing?

Comment: [ios wkwebview now showing javascript alert dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26898941/6521116)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A little late but I would like to add my experience for future reference. The answer of @Bon Bon brought me on the path to the solution while I was trying to make things work with **Swift 3** and IOS 10, in which case the code needs some modifications.
Firstly you need to implement also `WKUIDelegate`, so add it to the `ViewController` declaration:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
```

Then when you instantiate the `WKWebView` object, as for example like so:

```
self.webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
```

you need also to assign the correct value to the `uiDelegate` property of the instance:

```
self.webView?.uiDelegate = self
```

Then finally you can use the code provided by @Bon Bon, but note that there are some little differences required by Swift 3, as for example, the name of the `presentViewController` method becomes `present` :

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler()
    }))

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler(true)
    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler(false)
    }))

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String, defaultText: String?, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: prompt, preferredStyle: .alert)

    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.text = defaultText
    }

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        if let text = alertController.textFields?.first?.text {
            completionHandler(text)
        } else {
            completionHandler(defaultText)
        }

    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

        completionHandler(nil)

    }))

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

That made `alert`, `confirmation` and `text input` to work correctly within `WKWebView`, without any compiler warning in **Xcode 8**. I'm not an expert Swift programmer, so any useful comment about correctness of the code would be very appreciated.

Comment: Thanks to you @Bon Bon for your original code, without it I would have had  a long night of work!

Comment: `preferredStyle: .alert` should be set for prompt instead `preferredStyle: .actionSheet` - without this change I'm getting error saying text field could be added only to alert

Comment: It appears prompt() fails with signal SIGABRT for me using Swift 4 unless you apply godblessstrawberry comment.  @wiredolphin may be good to change your answer correction to use preferredStyle: .alert

Comment: this should be the selected answer

Comment: For iPad preferredStyle must be .alert because otherwise an exception will be thrown

Answer (score 20):

You also need to set the uiDelegate on the WKWebView.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var wkWebView: WKWebView!

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
        wkWebView.uiDelegate = self
        wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(wkWebView!)
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert")!
        wkWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String,
                 initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
                 completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let title = NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "OK Button")
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: title, style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        alert.addAction(ok)
        present(alert, animated: true)
        completionHandler()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        wkWebView.evaluateJavaScript("alert('Hello from evaluateJavascript()')", completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

For `confirm()` and `prompt()` see the other delegate methods.

Comment: Yes this was set. Are you able to get js to work with WKWebView? I had to change all my native js alert/confirm dialogs to use bootbox dialog to get past the problem.

Comment: Yes, it works fine for me. Was your controller your UIDelegate or did you have a seperate object? Perhaps the delegate was being deallocated?

Comment: You are able to open native js dialog boxes wiht this code?

Comment: Yes. If you upload an example project to Github I can take a look why it's not working for you.

Comment: This not work for wkwebview's  evaluateJavaScript(), refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/43600624/6521116

Answer (score 8):

Here is a sample code for various javascript alert implementation in Swift:

It's all about converting info in javascript alert into **native UI**, and call the completionHandler() to send the user action back to javascript engine.

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: () -> Void) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler()
        }))

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(true)
        }))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(false)
        }))

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String, defaultText: String?, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: (String?) -> Void) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: prompt, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
            textField.text = defaultText
        }

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action) in
            if let text = alertController.textFields?.first?.text {
                completionHandler(text)
            } else {
                completionHandler(defaultText)
            }

        }))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: { (action) in

            completionHandler(nil)

        }))

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: How do you modify this code so it also works with ipad?

Comment: I needed the following line which I put as an edit to this answer:     alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

Comment: @applecrusher  
Did you run into an issue where the app crashes if you try to show multiple alerts at once? Works great on iPhones but crashes on iPads.