# alert() not working in WKWebview evaluateJavaScript()

Tags: javascript, ios, swift3, wkwebview

I don't why my question is marked as duplicate of **[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898941/ios-wkwebview-not-showing-javascript-alert-dialog)**, first I execute javascript code with evaluateJavaScript as the question title shows which it's apparently different from that quesiton. What's more I've noted that I've try the answer in that question without no success at the end of my question body.

I use `wkwebview.evaluateJavaScript()` funciton to execute javascript in the wkwebview of swift3. But the `alert()` didnot open the alert dialog. And there is no errors and issues shows. While I can use `evaluateJavaScript()` to execute javascript code to modify the page content.

```
class WebViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var wk:WKWebView!
    self.wk.navigationDelegate = self
    self.wk.uiDelegate = self
    self.wk.scrollView.delegate = self
    self.wk.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"

    ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        self.wk = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY+20, width: frame.width, height: frame.height-70), configuration: config)
        self.wk.navigationDelegate = self
        ...
    }


    ...
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Finished navigation to url \(String(describing: webView.url))")
        //self.wk.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'sssssssssssssss';", completionHandler: nil)          //this works well
        self.wk.evaluateJavaScript("alert('aaaaaaa');", completionHandler: nil)     //this not show the alert dialog
    }
    ...
}
```

I also refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898941/ios-wkwebview-not-showing-javascript-alert-dialog) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27067168/6521116), while that question is not on evaluateJavaScript. I add `WKUIDelegate` for my `WebViewController` and add `self.wk.uiDelegate = self` to my `viewDidLoad()`, but nothing changes.

added, below the console.log() put the log in the console, while alert() not pop up the dialog.  And the UIAlertController also works.

```
self.wk.evaluateJavaScript("alert('aa');console.log('1234');var rect = document.getElementById('liveMovie').getBoundingClientRect();[rect.left, rect.top];") {
    (result, error) -> Void in
    if((result) != nil)
    {
        self.player?.view?.frame.origin.x = (result as! Array)[0]
        self.player?.view?.frame.origin.y = (result as! Array)[1]
    }
}

let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
     if(true)
     {
     }
}))
```

Comment: You have no mention of the `runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage` delegate method. Can add that code to your question?

Comment: I didn't use that method in my code. The `UIAlertController` can works in my code, but the `evaluateJavaScript` can not `alert()`

Comment: That's why it doesn't work then. This method is called when javascript fires and `alert()`. It is then up to you in this method to decide what to do about it. See the example in the answer linked below.

Comment: To sum what Onato means: The linked question *is* relevant. The flow would be like this: You evaluate JS with an `alert()`, this triggers the webview to call its delegate's `runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage`. If that is not implemented, the alert won't open. Whether you call the JS `alert()` from something passed to `evaluateJavaScript` or the site calls it itself (i.e. it's already in its code) doesn't matter. I wonder why you'd believe there's a difference?

Comment: @Gero It's my fault here. I've not much experience with WKWebview. I've experience wiht android's XWalkview, and there execute `alert` needn't to implement alert with java code. So here I also missed thought I don't need to implementation the alert delegate with swift. When I saw that question, I thought it use swift code to pop the alert dialog. But now, I have gained cognition about how swift execute the `alert`, I take my word before. Thank you all the same.

Comment: @KrisRoofe No problem, it's all good. Just wanted to make sure you get a solution (and Onato the well-deserved accept). :) WKWebView is indeed still a bit weird in some places (more powerful than UIWebView, but still not done with everything, sadly) so it can be confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a working example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34759503/215748). It seems you mightn't have implemented the WKUIDelegate method correctly.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to implement the required WKUIDelegate methods, in your case you need to implement:

```
optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, 
    runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, 
         initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, 
        completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
{
    // parameter **message** will hold your actual alert message.

    // Write Your Customised code to display the alert message
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's my fault here. I've not much experience with `WKWebview`. I've experience with android's `XWalkview`, and there execute `alert` needn't to implement `alert` with java code. So here I also missed thought I don't need to implementation the `alert` `delegate` with swift.

From **[answer of Onato](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44317827/6521116)**, I learned how swift execute the `alert` `prompt` and `confirm`, I lost the implementation of these delegate. So I refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40316507/6521116), add below implementation, everything works.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
             completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler()
    }))

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
             completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler(true)
    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler(false)
    }))

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String, defaultText: String?, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
             completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: prompt, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.text = defaultText
    }

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        if let text = alertController.textFields?.first?.text {
            completionHandler(text)
        } else {
            completionHandler(defaultText)
        }
    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler(nil)
    }))

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```