# WKWebView javascript alert, prompt, confirm won't work

Tags: javascript, xcode, swift3, wkwebview

hi I'm implementing simple WKWebView appplication and I want to be able to ask user for input via prompt dialogue, I tried to use solution mentioned here

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/40157363/1665293

but I'm not sure how should it work when implemented - should this just add extension to WKWebView for triggering e.g. regular `alert()` from javascript or I should pass some different instructions in js to trigger this native alert?

so my question is:
1) how this should work when implemented
2) what am I missing in implementation

here's my controller code (giving whole controller, as I dont know what could be important here)

thanks in advance!

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController:
    UIViewController
    , WKNavigationDelegate
    , UIScrollViewDelegate
    , WKUIDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
    let getUrlAtDocumentStartScript = "GetUrlAtDocumentStart"
    let getUrlAtDocumentEndScript = "GetUrlAtDocumentEnd"

    override func loadView() {
        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self

        //for prompt
        self.webView?.uiDelegate = self

        view = webView
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {//white status bar
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        webView.isOpaque = false //removes white flash on WKWebView load
        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 41/255, green: 45/255, blue: 91/255, alpha: 1)
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

        do {

            let paid = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["paid"]  as? Bool;
            var fileName = "none"

            if(paid!){
                fileName = "index-ios-wvd-inlined--paid"
            } else {
                fileName = "index-ios-wvd-inlined"
            }
            guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "html")
                else {
                    print ("File reading error")
                    return
            }


            let contents =  try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)
            let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            webView.loadHTMLString(contents as String, baseURL: baseUrl)

        }
        catch {
            print ("File HTML error")
        }

    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {//white status bar
        return .lightContent
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        webView.scrollView.bounces = false;
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.scrollView.delegate = self //disable zoom


        //for haptics
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.addScript(script: WKUserScript.getUrlScript(scriptName: getUrlAtDocumentStartScript), scriptHandlerName:getUrlAtDocumentStartScript, scriptMessageHandler: self, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart)
        config.addScript(script: WKUserScript.getUrlScript(scriptName: getUrlAtDocumentEndScript), scriptHandlerName:getUrlAtDocumentEndScript, scriptMessageHandler: self, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd)
        webView = WKWebView(frame:  UIScreen.main.bounds, configuration: config)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }

    //disable zoom        
    func viewForZooming(in: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return nil;
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tapped(i:Int) {
        print("Triggering haptic #\(i)")

        switch i {
        case 1:
            let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
            generator.notificationOccurred(.error)

        case 2:
            let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
            generator.notificationOccurred(.success)

        case 3:
            let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
            generator.notificationOccurred(.warning)

        case 4:
            let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
            generator.impactOccurred()

        case 5:
            let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
            generator.impactOccurred()

        case 6:
            let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
            generator.impactOccurred()

        default:
            let generator = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()
            generator.selectionChanged()
        }
    }

    //alert/prompt/confirm dialogs
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
                 completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler()
        }))

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
                 completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(true)
        }))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(false)
        }))

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String, defaultText: String?, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
                 completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: prompt, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.text = defaultText
        }

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            if let text = alertController.textFields?.first?.text {
                completionHandler(text)
            } else {
                completionHandler(defaultText)
            }
        }))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(nil)
        }))

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

//sending scripts commands to JS and back
extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        switch message.name {

        case getUrlAtDocumentStartScript:
            tapped(i: message.body as! Int)
            //print("start: \(message.body)")

        case getUrlAtDocumentEndScript:
            tapped(i: message.body as! Int)
            //print("tapped: \(message.body)")

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

extension WKUserScript {
    class func getUrlScript(scriptName: String) -> String {
        return "webkit.messageHandlers.\(scriptName).postMessage(1)"
    }
}

extension WKWebView {
    func loadUrl(string: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: string) {
            load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }
}

extension WKWebViewConfiguration {
    func addScript(script: String, scriptHandlerName:String, scriptMessageHandler: WKScriptMessageHandler, injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTime) {
        let userScript = WKUserScript(source: script, injectionTime: injectionTime, forMainFrameOnly: false)
        userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
        userContentController.add(scriptMessageHandler, name: scriptHandlerName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

okay, so I found answers and solution,

1) this will add support for native JS methods. `alert()`, `prompt()` and `confirm()` could be called from JS or via

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("confirm('Hello from evaluateJavascript()')", completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

2) here's the implementation of methods I'm using right now (I insert this in the bottom of `ViewController` class:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String,
                 initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
                 completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let title = NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "OK Button")
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: title, style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        alert.addAction(ok)
        present(alert, animated: true)
        completionHandler()
    }

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String,
                 defaultText: String?,
                 initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
                 completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: prompt, preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.text = defaultText
        }

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            if let text = alert.textFields?.first?.text {
                completionHandler(text)
            } else {
                completionHandler(defaultText)
            }

        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

            completionHandler(nil)

        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

//        if ipad will crash on this do this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772973/ios-wkwebview-javascript-alert-crashing-on-ipad?noredirect=1&lq=1):
//        if let presenter = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
//            presenter.sourceView = self.view
//        }
//        
//        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String,
                 initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
                 completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(true)
        }))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(false)
        }))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

also to the bottom of `viewDidLoad()` I added this code:

```
webView.uiDelegate = self
webView.navigationDelegate = self
view.addSubview(webView!)
```

Adding full code into collapsed snippet - in case someone will be confused how exactly this should be used:

```js
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController:
    UIViewController
    , WKNavigationDelegate
    , UIScrollViewDelegate
    , WKUIDelegate
{

    //wk webvew set

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
    let getUrlAtDocumentStartScript = "GetUrlAtDocumentStart"
    let getUrlAtDocumentEndScript = "GetUrlAtDocumentEnd"
//webkit.messageHandlers.GetUrlAtDocumentEnd.postMessage('1')
    
    override func loadView() {
        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
        
        //for prompt ??
        self.webView?.uiDelegate = self

        view = webView
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {//white status bar
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        webView.isOpaque = false //removes white flash on WKWebView load
        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 41/255, green: 45/255, blue: 91/255, alpha: 1)
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        
        do {

            let paid = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["paid"]  as? Bool;
            var fileName = "none"

            if(paid!){
                fileName = "index-ios-wvd-inlined--paid"
            } else {
                fileName = "index-ios-wvd-inlined"
            }
            guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "html")
                else {
                    // File Error
                    print ("File reading error")
                    return
            }


            let contents =  try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)
            let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            webView.loadHTMLString(contents as String, baseURL: baseUrl)
            
        }
        catch {
            print ("File HTML error")
        }
        
    }
    
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {//white status bar
        return .lightContent
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        webView.scrollView.bounces = false;
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //disable zoom
        webView.scrollView.delegate = self
        
        
        
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.addScript(script: WKUserScript.getUrlScript(scriptName: getUrlAtDocumentStartScript), scriptHandlerName:getUrlAtDocumentStartScript, scriptMessageHandler: self, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart)
        config.addScript(script: WKUserScript.getUrlScript(scriptName: getUrlAtDocumentEndScript), scriptHandlerName:getUrlAtDocumentEndScript, scriptMessageHandler: self, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd)
        webView = WKWebView(frame:  UIScreen.main.bounds, configuration: config)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView)

        
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView!)
         
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    
    func viewForZooming(in: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return nil;
    }

    //disable zoom
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tapped(i:Int) {
        print("Running \(i)")
        
        switch i {
        case 1:
            let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
            generator.notificationOccurred(.error)
            
        case 2:
            let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
            generator.notificationOccurred(.success)
            
        case 3:
            let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
            generator.notificationOccurred(.warning)
            
        case 4:
            let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
            generator.impactOccurred()
            
        case 5:
            let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
            generator.impactOccurred()
            
        case 6:
            let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
            generator.impactOccurred()
            
        default:
            let generator = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()
            generator.selectionChanged()
        }
    }
    
    
    //default alert/confirm/prompt dialogs
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String,
                 initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
                 completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let title = NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "OK Button")
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: title, style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        alert.addAction(ok)
        present(alert, animated: true)
        completionHandler()
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String,
                 defaultText: String?,
                 initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
                 completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: prompt, preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        alert.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.text = defaultText
        }
        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            if let text = alert.textFields?.first?.text {
                completionHandler(text)
            } else {
                completionHandler(defaultText)
            }
            
        }))
        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            
            completionHandler(nil)
            
        }))
        
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
//        if ipad will crash on this try to uncomment (based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772973/ios-wkwebview-javascript-alert-crashing-on-ipad?noredirect=1&lq=1):
//        if let presenter = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
//            presenter.sourceView = self.view
//        }
//        
//        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String,
                 initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
                 completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(true)
        }))
        
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(false)
        }))
        
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("confirm('Hello from evaluateJavascript()')", completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        switch message.name {
            
        case getUrlAtDocumentStartScript:
            tapped(i: message.body as! Int)
            //print("start: \(message.body)")
            
        case getUrlAtDocumentEndScript:
            tapped(i: message.body as! Int)
            //print("tapped: \(message.body)")
            
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

extension WKUserScript {
    class func getUrlScript(scriptName: String) -> String {
        return "webkit.messageHandlers.\(scriptName).postMessage(1)"
    }
}

extension WKWebView {
    func loadUrl(string: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: string) {
            load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }
}

extension WKWebViewConfiguration {
    func addScript(script: String, scriptHandlerName:String, scriptMessageHandler: WKScriptMessageHandler, injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTime) {
        let userScript = WKUserScript(source: script, injectionTime: injectionTime, forMainFrameOnly: false)
        userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
        userContentController.add(scriptMessageHandler, name: scriptHandlerName)
    }
}
```