# WKWebView - How to fill Prompt Dialog Box

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I'm trying to learn how to web scrape and I've come stuck on this problem where a prompt dialog box appears as a log in form, and I'm having no luck as to how to fill the text fields in the dialogue box. There is a log in and password field. How would you go about doing this?

[image: Here is the kind of thing I'm talking about.]

I've tried using `WKUIDelegate` and implementing:

```
init() {
    super.init()
    self.webView.uiDelegate = self
}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print(" >> Web view wants to show alert - \(message)")
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String, defaultText: String?, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
        print(" >> Web view wants to prompt for text - \(prompt)")
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        print(" >> Web view wants confirmation - \(message)")
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WKWebView javascript alert, prompt, confirm won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46456544/wkwebview-javascript-alert-prompt-confirm-wont-work)