# WkWebView JavaScript script not working

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, wkwebview

My Goal is to send data from iOS device to WkWebView. After researching on how to do this task I get to know that it can be done via executing JavaScript function via WkWebView, therefore, I tried calling just a simple alert function:

```
@interface UIWebViewController ()  <WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate>



@end

WKWebView *webView;

-(void)webView:(WKWebView )webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation )navigation{

    NSString* javascriptString = @"alert('Hi');";
    [webView evaluateJavaScript:javascriptString completionHandler:nil];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
    webView.navigationDelegate = self;   

}
```

Unfortunately I am not able to see any alert with that code?

Can you let me know what kind of silly mistake I am doing in the above code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS WKWebView not showing javascript alert() dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898941/ios-wkwebview-not-showing-javascript-alert-dialog)

Comment: The problem is not the calling of the JavaScript, but that `alert()` doesn't show if you don't implement the delegate, see the link above.

Comment: I have already implemented WKUIDelegate to my controller.

Comment: and does `runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage` get called?

Comment: I don't have any reference to runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage  in my code.

Comment: That is the problem. WKWebView does not show alerts, but will call this method on its `UIDelegate` instead. Please see the link in the first comment on how to implement this method.