# Flutter: passing data to WebView

Tags: angular, flutter, webview, location

I get the location in my Flutter app. I have a WebView and I want to pass the location inside it 
(to handle it after in the site opened within the webview).

```
var userLocation = Provider.of<UserLocation>(context);
```

And my WebView:

```
WebView(
      initialUrl: widget.url,
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
 )
```

Is there a way to do it?
My goal is like a binding between flutter and angular sending continuous location data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run some Javascript in Flutter Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350001/run-some-javascript-in-flutter-webview)

Comment: Can't you pass it through the url?

Comment: @Augustin R url accepted 1 parameter, that's the link to my site

Comment: @Sahandevs no, I don't want to run JS. I want to pass the location parameter to WebView

Comment: @EdoardoTavilla do you mean browser location ( url ) or coordinates ?

Comment: @Sahandevs coordinates

Comment: if you are sending from flutter to js, you can define a function in browser window object like `window.onReceiveCoords = (coords) => console.log();` and in flutter call `flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript("window.onReceiveCoords({x: 1, y: 3}")`

Comment: It seems that this is some new feature and I've found [this GitHub ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27472) asking to support this functionality and it is still open. It would be nice if you could also provide what you have done so far, like [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

normally To receive data from flutter we add js function in html

```
function fromFlutter(location) {
    document.getElementById("locationId").innerHTML = location;
    sendBack();
}
```

and then in flutter create a web view controller then

```
_controller.evaluateJavascript('fromFlutter("From Flutter")');
```

or for variable containing location

```
_controller.evaluateJavascript('fromFlutter("$locationVar")');
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this same problem, and the original question mentioned Angular which is what I am also using. So let me share my solution.

You can pass route params to an angular page, so if you have the data going from your flutter app to a database, say Firebase, then you can pass the specific document ID as a route param in flutter webview, and any data you are passing in flutter will auto sync up to the route that you have called in angular.