# Running JavaScript in iframe in flutter_inappwebview

Tags: javascript, flutter, iframe, webview

I know how to run JavaScript in the top level document using [Run some Javascript in Flutter Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350001/run-some-javascript-in-flutter-webview), but I am not sure how I would write JavaScript to interact with iframes within the document.

Can somebody explain whether it's possible, and, if so, can you attach an example?

Comment: Is this helpful to you? [Control iframe content with javascript/html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19498836/10999353)

Comment: That works, but only on iframes from the same origin. I want to also interact with iframes from different origins.

Comment: You can only achieve that due to the cross-domain policy.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9393545/10999353

Answer (score 0):

*You can only achieve that if you own both sites due to the cross-domain policy.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9393545/10999353