# How to automate a Flutter Application

Tags: android, flutter, automation, flutter-test, flutterdriver

I am working on a project in which I am using webview to open a website.
I want the application to automatically fill data in the required fields and log in by reading the OTP and perform various actions depending on various events like people create automation using Selenium.
I have seen some articles on flutter automation using flutter driver but they are mostly for widget tests and it's not properly clear to me.

Can anyone provide an insight on how can I properly implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To automate something in a `WebView`, you can use Javascript interfaces.

Comment: How exactly?
Can you provide some guide or reference it will be really helpful :)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350001/run-some-javascript-in-flutter-webview

Answer (score 0):

You can execute JavaScript in your WebView

[Here is a tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-webview-javascript-communication-inappwebview-5-403088610949)

Once you can execute your javascript, you just have to get your input and fill it.

For example:

```js
const inp = document.getElementById("your_input");
inp.value = "some text";
```

Comment: Will my application be able to detect various fields and fill data in it in webview ?

Comment: @RahulKumarJha sure, you should learn javascript basis, it would be very helpful ! :)