# WKWebView - JavaScript alert function not working in Objective-C

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

If my question/wording is a bit off, I apologize as I'm new to Objective-C and Xcode.
Anyways,
I am using the WebView property to open my website. Once on my site I have a   form on a page within my website that when a user submits it brings up an alert stating "Message sent! Should the seller take interest they will reach out to you". Here's the html code from my website.

`<script type="text/javascript">
function SendAlert() {
  alert("Message sent! Should the seller take interest they will reach out to you");
}
</script>`

While I'm on the native Safari app from my iPhone the `Sendalert()` function works fine, not when I'm on the app from my Xcode project.
Here's the code I have in my ViewController.m file.

`-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];`

`NSString *myURL = @"https://example.com/";
[_myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL]]];
    return;
}`

What am I missing that is preventing my alert() functions from showing in my app? If there's something you need that I didn't list please let me know!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS WKWebView not showing javascript alert() dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898941/ios-wkwebview-not-showing-javascript-alert-dialog)

Comment: @nakano531 Alright, thanks, I'll take a look and post another reply if it isn't and I need additional help.