# WKWebView popup not showing up

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I've been working on a simple app that makes a webview of a website where students can take exams.

So basically the problem I have is that when students are done, they have to click on a button that will send the answers. 
A popup will appear to make them confirm. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GhB8.png
Except that it doesn't show up. Nothing happens when the button is pushed.
It works flawlessly on Safari and I've noticed that it works on the deprecated webview (UIWebview) but I've been trying to make it work on WKWebView.

I'm definitely no swift expert so I apologize if the answer is easy. I've been trying to find some answers about my problem but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Thank you in advance for any help,

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class webViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let lien = "***"
        if let url = URL(string: lien) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            _ = webview.load(request);
        }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the code please? without code its hard to fix

Comment: I've added the code

Comment: Did you use Constraints when you'd been adding the WKWebView?

Comment: I think you need to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898941/ios-wkwebview-not-showing-javascript-alert-dialog

Comment: I did use Constraints in every position.

I've read that topic, do I just need to implement those 3 functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also faced similar issue, mine was popup for connecting facebook won't show in WKWebView but works fine on safari browser.

This code was causing the issue.

```
- (WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures {
//This condition was causing the problem while trying to get popup
    if (!navigationAction.targetFrame.isMainFrame) {
        [webView loadRequest:navigationAction.request];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

I changed it to following code and it worked

```
- (WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures {
    if (navigationAction.targetFrame == nil) {
        NSURL *tempURL = navigationAction.request.URL;
        NSURLComponents *URLComponents = [[NSURLComponents alloc] init];
        URLComponents.scheme = [tempURL scheme];
        URLComponents.host = [tempURL host];
        URLComponents.path = [tempURL path];
        if ([URLComponents.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"https://example.com/Account/ExternalLogin"]) {
            WKWebView *webViewtemp = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds configuration:configuration];
            webViewtemp.UIDelegate = self;
            webViewtemp.navigationDelegate = self;
            [self.view addSubview:webViewtemp];
            return webViewtemp;
        } else {
            [webView loadRequest:navigationAction.request];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Swift version:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
        let tempURL = navigationAction.request.url
        var components = URLComponents()
        components.scheme = tempURL?.scheme
        components.host = tempURL?.host
        components.path = (tempURL?.path)!
        if components.url?.absoluteString == "https://example.com/Account/ExternalLogin" {
            let webViewtemp = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
            webViewtemp.uiDelegate = self
            webViewtemp.navigationDelegate = self
            self.view.addSubview(webViewtemp)
            return webViewtemp
        } else {
            webView.load(navigationAction.request)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Hmm any chance you have that code in swift language?

Comment: How do I execute this function? I'm not sure which parameters I'm supposed to enter

Comment: This lead me to my fix. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

My solution was implementing the `WKUIDelegate` and adding the functions for the different scenarios (alerts) that the web view may present:

```
extension WKWebViewController: WKUIDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "OK button"), style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler()
        }))

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "OK button"), style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(true)
        }))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "Cancel button"), style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(false)
        }))

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String, defaultText: String?, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: prompt, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.text = defaultText
        }

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "OK button"), style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            if let text = alertController.textFields?.first?.text {
                completionHandler(text)
            } else {
                completionHandler(defaultText)
            }
        }))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "Cancel button"), style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(nil)
        }))

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

When web view demands the new popup window than **UIDelegate of WKWebView** will come in picture.

Follow these steps to show POP-Up view in WKWebView

1. Take a another web-view

   ```
   private var popupWebView: WKWebView?
   ```
2. Assign the uiDelegate of your main web-view to *self*

   ```
   webView?.uiDelegate = self
   ```
3. Confirm the WKUIDelegate of to your controller

   ```
   extension PaisaPalVC: WKUIDelegate {
       func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
           popupWebView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
           popupWebView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
           popupWebView?.navigationDelegate = self
           popupWebView?.uiDelegate = self
           if let newWebview = popupWebView {
               view.addSubview(newWebview)
           }
           return popupWebView ?? nil
       }
       func webViewDidClose(_ webView: WKWebView) {
           webView.removeFromSuperview()
           popupWebView = nil
       }
   }
   ```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Precisely. What I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the other way round and it worked for me. Here is the code:
Create a instance of WebView

```
fileprivate var webView: WKWebView?
```

Initialize instance and make assign it to view.

```
override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
    webView?.uiDelegate = self
    webView?.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}
```

Thereafter, just add the following delegate method:

```
func webView(_: WKWebView, createWebViewWith _: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures _: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    self.webView?.load(navigationAction.request)
    return nil
}
```

Voila! Everything will work same as `UIWebView`.

Note: You won't be able to tap few links on the WebSite, because they would be HTTP instead of HTTPS. WKWebView by default blocks all HTTP requests which aren't secure.

To bypass, just add `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` as `true` in `info.plist` file.